# Python scoring pandas, string validation

Tags: python, pandas, iterator

I am trying to add a score of "1" for each participant (represented by a row) having two attribute (column) values equals to "On".

However, even though the cells both contain "On" this does not assign a score of 1.

Any simpler solution?

```
for row in reduction.itertuples():
    if str(reduction['q1-1']) == "On" and str(reduction['q1-2']) == "On":
        q1 = 1
    else:
        q1 = 0
    print(q1)
```

Comment: What do you think `q1` is in the loop?

Comment: A score per participant .

Answer (score 1):

If need new column `q` create boolean mask and cast to integers:

```
reduction = pd.DataFrame({
    'q1-1': ['On','On','Off','Off'],
    'q1-2': ['On','Off','On','Off']
})

mask = (reduction['q1-1'].astype(str) == "On") & (reduction['q1-2'].astype(str)  == "On")

#alternative
mask = (reduction[['q1-1','q1-2']].astype(str) == "On").all(axis=1)
reduction['q'] = mask.astype(int)
print (reduction)
  q1-1 q1-2  q
0   On   On  1
1   On  Off  0
2  Off   On  0
3  Off  Off  0
```

Explanation of alternative:

Cast columns selected by subset to strings and compare by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) `==`:

```
print (reduction[['q1-1','q1-2']].astype(str) == "On")
    q1-1   q1-2
0   True   True
1   True  False
2  False   True
3  False  False
```

Then check if [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) values are `True`s per rows:

```
print ((reduction[['q1-1','q1-2']].astype(str) == "On").all(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

`q1` has no meaning in your loop. Nor does `print` update a dataframe. If you wish to use a loop, you would need to use [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), something like:

```
for row in df[['q1-1', 'q1-2']].itertuples():
    if (row[1] == 'On') and (row[2] == 'On'):
        df.loc[row.Index, 'Score'] = 1
```

But this is inefficient as it iterates each row in a Python-level loop. With Pandas, you should aim for a vectorised solution:

```
mask = reduction[['q1-1', 'q-2']].astype(str).eq('On').all(1)
reduction['score'] = mask.astype(int)
```